# How do I specify an assembly file name for a compiled ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net

I have read under: Compiling Web Application Projects (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983464.aspx)

... this compilation model creates a single assembly, you can specify attributes, such as assembly name and version.

You can supply a PATH (directory name only) in the Visual Studio "Build Options".

But where can the file name for the assembly be specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a C# ASP.NET Web Application, see the AssemblyInfo.cs file, it's located in a special folder named "Properties". For VB.NET, you usually have to select your project and click the "Show All Files" button: Then you should be able to find AssemblyInfo.vb in the special folder "My Project".

Depending on the version of .NET and Visual Studio, the AssemblyInfo file may be located in different locations and it may not be visible per default, but it's always been named AssemblyInfo and it's always there, hiding somewhere. :)